# How to Add Data on Multi Dimensional Dictionary on vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

```
Dim texts As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
```

How can I add data to the above dictionary?

Comment: Your `texts` dictionary is declared as a local variable in the Load event.  That means once the form loads, the dictionary will no longer exist (so your question is irrelevant as is).  Adding to that collection is no different - you add (`texts.Add(...)`) the difference is that you add another dictionary.

Comment: It was test so I just need to know the method of Adding Data into Multi dimensional dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you use visual studio, you should get a hint when you type `texts.Add(`

[image]

The key is a `String`, and the value is a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`. One way to add the value is to declare a new dictionary beforehand, then add it

```
Dim texts As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))()

Dim innerEnglish As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
innerEnglish.Add("A", "Antelope")
innerEnglish.Add("B", "Bear")
texts.Add("English", innerEnglish)

Dim innerLatin As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
innerLatin.Add("O", "Oryx")
innerLatin.Add("U", "Ursa")
texts.Add("Latin", innerLatin)
```

They can be keyed as such

```
texts("Latin")("U") ' returns "Ursa"
texts("English")("B") ' returns "Bear"
```